# iCloud only seems to work on start up

Tags: iphone, ipad, icloud

I'm trying to create an iCloud app that uses Core Data. To do so, I use a single instance of `UIManagedDocument`.  For `persistentStoreOptions`, I set "Database.data" for `NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentNameKey` and -iCloudURL-/CoreData_Logs for `NSPersistentStoreUbiquitousContentURLKey`. As by Apple suggested, I open the document like so:

```
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[urlOfDatabase path]])
{
    [_database openWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) { ... }];
}
else
{
    [_database saveToURL:urlOfDatabase
        forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating
       completionHandler:^(BOOL success) { ... }];
}
```

Also, I registered for `NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification`s, and merge the context from the notification in that method.

To test the app, I use an iPad and an iPhone. When I run it on one device, add some data, and open it up on the other device, the correct data is displayed. If I however add data while the app is running on both devices, it either doesn't update (I've waited for at least 10 minutes once) or it updates after a few minutes but only with a whole bunch of error messages: "The item failed to download.".

Did I miss something (hopefully obvious) in my set up?